# Next.js how to disable source maps?

Tags: next.js, source-maps

My nextjs project always have source map after build in chunks folder, how to disable the source map
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUWLP.png)

**next.config.js**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1GhE.png)

**scripts in package.json**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PEZu.png)

no setting for source map in next.config.js, try to add "productionBrowserSourceMaps: false" to next.config.js, but not work

Comment: Why exactly should that be "too much" source maps?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.